usbc wired headset is randomly being disconnect and not detected
Lately I have an issue where my wired USB-C headset just stops working. Unplugging/Plugging it back is also not working. At that point it's not even being detected.
This usually happens when the laptop goes into a sleep mod,e and the issue is resolved after a full reboot of the machine.
Is there a quick solution to this that doesn't include a reboot? Like can I just manually refresh the USB-C port to remedy the issue? If so, what would the command be?
